# What is the output of this C code (run without any command line arguments)?

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, argv, argc

What is the output of this C code (run without any command line arguments)?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    while (*argv  !=  NULL)
    printf("%s\n", *(argv++));
     return 0;
}
```

In this program argv gives the base address of array of `char` pointer so

```
while(*argv !=NULL)
```

condition is true and this should give the compile time error because of 
`*(argv++)`, is not it? But it is showing some output why?

Comment: [Did you try it ? What result did you get ?](http://ideone.com/ZF08IY)

Comment: In the code shown `char *argv[]` is exactly 100% the same as `char **argv`. I like the last format better: there is no array anywhere. You might like to read section 6 of the [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: @pmg: each to their own, but I tend to think of `char *argv[]` as an array of `char *`, i.e. an array of strings.

Comment: @PaulR: you can't `++` an array.

Comment: @pmg: true - I guess I make a mental distinction between a *conceptual* array (in this case a contiguous sequence of pointers) and an array in the strict "C language lawyer" sense.

Comment: @Paul what is ./prog in output?

Comment: Why isit not showing compile time error?

Comment: @Ananya: `./prog` is the first part of the command line - usually the name used to invoke the program (but not necessarily). In this case it's just running a program called `prog` with no further command line arguments. There is no compile error because there is nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: @Paul But post or preincrement should not do in base address of an array right?

Comment: Why is it showing the program name?

Comment: @Ananya: did you *read* any of the answers and comments below ? `argv[]` contains the program name (in element 0) and any command line arguments (in elements 1..argc-1).

Comment: yes, thank u for clearence.:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting shamelessly from the `C11` spec, chapter §5.1.2.2.1, (*emphasis mine*)

> —  The value of `argc` shall be non-negative.
>
> — `argv[argc]` shall be a null pointer.
>
> — If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, **the array members `argv[0]`through
>   `argv[argc-1]` inclusive shall contain pointers to strings, which are given
>   implementation-defined values by the host environment prior to program startup.** The
>   intent is to supply to the program information determined prior to program startup
>   from elsewhere in the hosted environment. If the host environment is not capable of
>   supplying strings with letters in both uppercase and lowercase, the implementation
>   shall ensure that the strings are received in lowercase.
>
> — If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the string pointed to by `argv[0]`
>   represents the program name; `argv[0][0]` shall be the null character if the
>   program name is not available from the host environment. **If the value of argc is
>   greater than one, the strings pointed to by `argv[1]` through `argv[argc-1]`
>   represent the program parameters.**

The snippet above is to simply print the supplied *program parameters.*

- `*argv  !=  NULL` is to check that we did not reach the end of `argv` array.
- `printf("%s\n", *(argv++));` , let's break it down,

  ```
  printf("%s\n", *argv));  //print the string pointed to by `argv`
  argv++;                  //increment argv to point to the next string
  ```

---

Now, coming to the question in "title"

> *[...] (run without any command line arguments)?*

well, in that case, the `argc` has a value of `1`, and only `argv[0]` hold a pointer to a string containing the program name. `argv[1]` points to `NULL` (or similar null pointer).

So, in the loop

- First condition check is success (`*argv` == `argv[0]` which is not NULL), it prints the program name
- `argv` is incremented as a side effect of the post-increment.
- Second iteration, `*argv` is the same as `argv[1]` now, which is NULL, condition is false, and it hits the final `return` statement.

---

The question in the body

> *this should give the compile time error because of  `*(argv++)`, is not it?*

No, it is not. Quoting chapter §6.7.6.3

> A declaration of a parameter as *‘‘array of type’’* shall be adjusted to *‘‘qualified pointer to
>   type’’*, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the [ and ] of the
>   array type derivation. [...]

Hence, `argv` is a modifiable lvalue and can be used as the operand for postfix increment operator here.

Comment: You might also want to explain that although the command line parameter is `char *argv[]`, this decays to `char **argv` within the function, which makes it legal to increment `argv`, i.e. `argv++` - I think this may be one of the things that is confusing the OP.

Comment: @PaulR I think I finally got it better, can you please review sir?